# mix local.hex fails from SSL after updating Erlang

Tags: ssl, erlang, elixir, homebrew, phoenix-framework

I was prompted to update Erlang on my machine and I did. Then when I restarted my server I was prompted to update using mix local.hex.

When i did this it gave me the following error.

[image]

mix local.hex --force didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out that I installed erlang originally without brew originally which is where the prompt came from. After I updated it, it caused an issue with mix local.hex.

I manually removed the folder /usr/local/lib/erlang and all erlang on my machine. I installed erlang using 'brew install erlang' and then ran 'brew link erlang'

This originally didn't work because I didn't have permission but then I ran the following to get permission.

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib

After that 'brew link erlang' worked and I was able to run 'mix local.hex' like normal.